# PHP using SELECT SUM

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, and was wondering if you could help with my select sum query?

I am wanting to add the total amount from my expenses table in my database based on user_id?

Here is what I have so far

```
<?php
    //sets up thisPage          
    $pageSize=10;
    if (isset($_POST["thisPage"])) 
        $thisPage = $_POST["thisPage"];
    else 
        $thisPage=1;

    //selects all distinct expenses that have been uploaded
    $dbQuery="SELECT SUM(amount) AS TotalExpenditure FROM expenses WHERE user_id =       '$userID'; ";

    echo $dbQuery;

    $dbResult=mysqli_query($db_connection, $dbQuery) or die (mysqli_error($db_connection));

    echo "<table> <thead>";
    //echo '<tr> <th>Project ID</th><th>Project Name</th></tr> </thead>';
    while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult)){
        // display row with expense
        echo '<tr> <td>'. $dbRow['amount'] .'</td>';
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
$dbRow['amount']
```

but you use

```
SUM(amount) AS TotalExpenditure
             // ^ this is the name (alias) of your column now
```

`TotalExpenditure` is the name of the amount, so the last part should be

```
echo '<tr> <td>'. $dbRow['TotalExpenditure'] .'</td> </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `TotalExpenditure` as key of your array, so

`$dbRow['TotalExpenditure']` instead of `$dbRow['TotalExpenditure']`?

You're giving an alias to your `count()` sql function so you have to use it